# Rendering a list of items in React with shared state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## Original Question

<strike>I'm trying to render a list of items using React. The key is that the items share a common state, which can be controlled by each item.</strike>

For the sake of simplicity, let's say we have an array of strings. We have a `List` component that maps over the array, and generates the `Item` components. Each `Item` has a button that when clicked, it changes the state of all the items in the list (I've included a code snippet to convey what I'm trying to do).

I'm storing the `state` at the `List` component, and passing down its value to each `Item` child via `props`. The issue I'm encountering is that the button click (within `Item`) is not changing the UI state at all. I believe the issue has to do with the fact that `items` is not changing upon clicking the button (rightfully so), so React doesn't re-render the list (I would have expected some kind of UI update given the fact that the prop `isEditing` passed onto `Item` changes when the `List` state changes).

How can I have React handle this scenario?

Note: there seems to be a script error when clicking the `Edit` button in the code snippet, but I don't run into it when I run it locally. Instead, no errors are thrown, but nothing in the UI gets updated either. When I debug it, I can see that the state change in `List` is not propagated to its children.

## Edited Question

Given the original question was not clear enough, I'm rephrasing it below.

#### Goal

I want to render a list of items in `React`. Each item should show a word, and an `Edit` button. The user should only be able edit one item at a time.

#### Acceptance Criteria

- Upon loading, the user sees a list of words with an `Edit` button next to each.
- When clicking `Edit` for item 1, only item 1 becomes editable and the `Edit` button becomes a `Save` button. The rest of the items on the list should no longer show their corresponding `Edit` button.
- Upon clicking `Save` for item 0, the new value is shown for that item. All the Edit buttons (for the rest of the items) should become visible again.

#### Problem

On my original implementation, I was storing an *edit* state in the parent component (`List`), but this state wasn't properly being propagated to its `Item` children.

NOTE: My original implementation is lacking on the state management logic, which I found out later was the main culprit (see my response below). It also has a *bind* bug as noted by @Zhang below. I'm leaving it here for future reference, although it's not really a good example.

Here's my original implementation:

```js
const items = ['foo', 'bar'];
 
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isEditing: false
    };
  }
  toggleIsEditing() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        isEditing: !prevState.isEditing
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((val) => (
          <Item value={val}
                toggleIsEditing={this.toggleIsEditing}
                isEditing={this.state.isEditing}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
 
class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <div>
          <span>{this.props.value}</span>
          { !this.props.isEditing &&
            (<button onClick={this.props.toggleIsEditing}>
              Edit
            </button>)
          }
          { this.props.isEditing &&
            (<div>
              <span>...Editing</span>
              <button onClick={this.props.toggleIsEditing}>
                Stop
              </button>
            </div>)
          }
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app" />
</body>
```

Comment: Better describe the original problem, please. What do you need to implement? It seems that the way you are trying to do it is totally wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I've rephrased my question to make it more clear. It was a good exercise, as it helped me solve my own problem as I had to rethink through my code. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution when I rephrased my question, by rethinking through my implementation. I had a few issues with my original implementation:

- The `this` in the non-lifecycle methods in the `List` class were not bound to the class scope (as noted by @ZhangBruce in his answer).
- The state management logic in `List` was lacking other properties to be able to handle the use case.

Also, I believe adding `state` to the `Item` component itself was important to properly propagate the updates. Specifically, adding `state.val` was key (from what I understand). There may be other ways (possibly simpler), in which case I'd be curious to know, but in the meantime here's my solution:

```js
const items = ['foo', 'bar'];
 
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editingFieldIndex: -1
    };
  }
  setEdit = (index = -1) => {
    this.setState({
      editingFieldIndex: index
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((val, index) => (
          <Item val={val}
                index={index}
                setEdit={this.setEdit} 
                editingFieldIndex={this.state.editingFieldIndex} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
 
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: props.val
    };
  }
  save = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      val: evt.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { index, setEdit, editingFieldIndex } = this.props;
    const { val } = this.state;
    
    const shouldShowEditableValue = editingFieldIndex === index;
    const shouldShowSaveAction = editingFieldIndex === index;
    const shouldHideActions = 
      editingFieldIndex !== -1 && editingFieldIndex !== index;
    
    const editableValue = (
      <input value={val} onChange={(evt) => this.save(evt)}/>
    )
    const readOnlyValue = (
      <span>{val}</span>
    )
    const editAction = (
      <button onClick={() => setEdit(index)}>
        Edit
      </button>
    )
    const saveAction = (
      <button onClick={() => setEdit()}>
        Save
      </button>
    )
    
    return (
      <li>
        <div>
        { console.log(`index=${index}`) }
        { console.log(`editingFieldIndex=${editingFieldIndex}`) }
        { console.log(`shouldHideActions=${shouldHideActions}`) }
        { 
          shouldShowEditableValue
            ? editableValue
            : readOnlyValue
        }
        {
          !shouldHideActions
            ? shouldShowSaveAction
              ? saveAction
              : editAction
            : ""
        }
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app" />
</body>
```

Comment: the problem with this design is that if some other child component edit item array after Item component is already rendered, Item component will have no way of knowing it. since it has it's own local state (which is  mostly evil).

Comment: @ZhangBruce how would you deal with that situation? What changes would you make?

Comment: I think your initial approach is correct, manage all your state in parent state, just need to make sure all method pass in props to change parent state needs to be binded with parent scope. or manage them in redux like library, but I think it's overkill for small projects.

Comment: @ZhangBruce got it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't bind the parent scope when passing toggleIsEditing to child component

```html
          <Item value={val}
                toggleIsEditing={this.toggleIsEditing.bind(this)}
                isEditing={this.state.isEditing}/>
```

Comment: Thanks @ZhangBruce. Good catch. That was definitely an issue, but it didn't get me all the way to the solution. I rephrased my question for clarity. In the process, I was able to solve my own question, which I'll be posting here briefly.